# Write a function when given one integer x ; returns e with the following approximation

Tags: java

![enter image description here][1]The question:

> Write a function with name ʻ expʼ that ,when given one integer x; returns 
>   with the following approximation. In this function, you should use previous two functions to calculate factorial and power.

This is my code;

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class ass7_q3 {
    public static int power(int x, int y)
    {
        int result = 1;
        for(int i = 1; i <= y; i++)
        {
            result = result * x;
        }
        return result;
    }
    public static int factorial(int n)
    {
        int fact = 1; 
        for(int i = 1; i<= n; i++)
        fact = fact * i;
        return fact;
    }
    public static int exp( int x)
    {
        int result;
        result = (power(x,x) / factorial(x) );
        return result;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner read = new Scanner(System.in);
        int sum = 0;
        int x;
        x = read.nextInt();
        for(int i=0; i<=10; i++)
        {
            sum = sum + exp(x);
        }
        System.out.println(sum);
    }

}
```

However, when I run this code, it always gives me the wrong answer.

What can I do?

Answer (score 1):

You should start by working with doubles instead of integers. You can't expect to approximate a Real number using only integer calculations.

For example, `power(x,x) / factorial(x)` would always return an integer, since both methods return an `int`.

Answer (score 0):

5/2 will return 2. You need cast it to double like ((double)5)/2 will return 2.5

Answer (score 0):

```
    You should think about range of integer ( in java 2,147,483,647)

   if your input is grater than 12, integer can not handle. 
   Factorial method will return wrong value. because 

    factorial(12)=479,001,600 but
    factorial(13)=6,227,020,800
```